# Expect not matching glob pattern

Tags: glob, expect

I have written a script to automate a login process, below is a portion of the code I am having trouble with.

```
spawn globalprotect connect --portal vpnconnect.myserver.com
expect { "1234myuser*:" } {
    send -- "\r"
}
```

The prompt when running the `globalprotect connect --portal vpnconnect.myserver.com` terminal output looks like this:

```
Retrieving configuration...                                            
vpnconnect.manchester.ac.uk - Enter login credentials
username(1234myuser):
```

At this stage I need to enter a newline (hence the `send -- "\r"`), however the glob pattern `"1234myuser*:"` does not match this sequence. below is the output from running `expect -d ./myscript.sh`

```
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./myscript.sh 
set argc 0
set argv0 "./myscript.sh"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file .manvpn.sh
spawn globalprotect connect --portal vpnconnect.myserver.com
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {141688}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "1234myuser*:" "? no
Retrieving configuration...                                            

expect: does "\r                                                                       \rRetrieving configuration...\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "1234myuser*:" "? no
vpnconnect.myserver.com - Enter login credentials
username(1234myuser):
expect: does "\r                                                                       \rRetrieving configuration...\r\nvpnconnect.myserver.com - Enter login credentials\r\nusername(1234myuser):" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "1234myuser*:" "? no
expect: timed out
```

**N.B** My username is obviously not `1234myuser`, but is similarly a sequence of alphanumeric characters.

**N.B** I have also tried similar `glob` patterns such as `*(1234myuser):"`, `"*1234myuser*"` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is using [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/Tcl.html) and in Tcl `{ "1234myuser*:" }` is the same as `" \"1234myuser*:\" "`.

You should just write:

```
expect "1234myuser*:" {
    send -- "\r"
}
```